# User name in view arguments and title of page

Tags: 7, views

I created a content type named "Post" and allowed certain roles to add posts on my website.

I also created a view that displays these posts, as a page and block view.
Now, I want to add a contextual filter to display posts from specific authors, but in filters I find only the author UID so that my URL is `post/1` and so on. Is there a way to have user name instead of user ID as wildcard in the URL?

I also want to set the page title such as "Posts of [user-name]", but I don't know if it is possible to do.

I'm very sorry, but I googled for this but I found nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add on "Relationships" (right side of your view edit page, under Advanced) "Content: Author". Now the name of the author (User: Name) will be available to you in fields and/or filters. You could also follow this: http://www.drupalden.co.uk/using-views-display-nodes-author-name